# How to connect to SQL Server from remote computer where computer A is able to connect while computer B is not

Tags: sql-server, connection

There are 3 computers on LAN say server, A and B. A connects to the server with no issues through a client application while B does not. The server is configured properly with remote connections enabled, port open and firewall configurations too. How to troubleshoot computer B to access server? Ping works from B to server.

Tried using ip address and server name, installed ssms and tried to connect to server. But B doesn't connect to the server. What might be wrong?

Comment: Verify connectivity to the port using TELNET or PowerShell. Powershell example: `powershell -Command echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Client.Connect('YourServerNameOrIpAddress', 1433)) 'success'`. If the command fails, the most likely cause is the port is blocked from the problem client.

Comment: powershell command executed and returned "success"

Comment: Network connectivity looks good, then. Add the SQL Server error message to your question. There may be additional information in the SQL Server error log if due to a login failure.